# Mob Grinder not spawning mobs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Windows 10/Bedrock

My Spawner is above ground, with a spawn area of 18x18, and a drop of 28 blocks. the collection area where id stand is at the bottom, and over a 60 minute time, not one mob has spawned

[image: Outside View]

[image: Inside view (spawn)]

[image]

Comment: there should be no other spawnable place in 128 blocks near your afk spot

Answer (score 1):

The mob spawning mechanics aren't the same in Bedrock Edition compared to Java Edition. In Bedrock, the cap on the number of mobs is lower which basically means that there can't be as many mobs in your world. Bedrock also has a feature where hostile mobs (maybe not just the hostile ones I'm not sure) don't despawn. This means that the number of mobs won't go down in your world unless you manually remove the mobs that are elsewhere in your world. The problem with this is that you don't know where the new mobs will spawn and they will most likely spawn. Therefor, hostile mob farming in Bedrock Edition is very difficult and if you want a productive farm, switch to Java.

Comment: Oh wow I never knew that... And another point on the ever growing list of reasons, why nobody interested in farming should ever play bedrock..
Why does the technical superior version have to be one with the worse list of features...

Answer (score 0):

Oh you have AFK nearby so the mobs can spawn. (Very close to the spawner, like in the same chunk.)

Answer (score 0):

please check that mob spawning is on and difficulty is NOT peaceful. Then make sure the light level is lower than 7 and stand in the same chunk as the spawner a few blocks more in the air

Comment: Great but I reccomentd more info

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Minecraft bedrock is a pain especially when it comes to spawning mechanics. You need a light level of 0, a solid block for them to spawn, you have to be extremely close to the spawning location and the mob cap is very low. Make sure any and all nearby areas are lit as well (including caves). Lastly, if all else fails I honestly recommend looking for mob spawners in said caves, they are far more reliable and since the caves are now absolutely massive they are quite abundant as well.